# secured file in storage laravel

Tags: laravel

i am uploading file in storage like this :
/storage/uploads/contract/19/12199/document.pdf

now i need to to allow only authenticated user to see those document , i use this route :
Route::get('/storage/{pathToFile}', function($pathToFile) {

```
if (auth()->user()) {
    return response()->file($pathToFile);
} else {
    return 'Nope, sorry bro, access denied!';
}
```

});

this didn't work , still all files can be acceded even if user not logged in .

any idea ?

thanks

Comment: You should use `auth()->check()` to determine if the current user is authenticated

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: i tried and it didn't work

Comment: i tried  this : Route::get('/storage/{pathToFile}', function($pathToFile) {
    return 'Nope, sorry bro, access denied!';
    

});
but it seems it has by pass , there is an issue in the route declaration

Answer (score 0):

Did you symlink the public folder to storage folder? If so it would still be accessible because default public entrypoint would be "public" folder so "[host]/storage" would be available in that folder.

What I did in the past was use S3 driver and set file [visibility](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-visibility) to private then use:

```
public function get($path, $image)
{
    $file = Storage::disk('s3')->get("private/images/". $path. "/" . $image);
    return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
}
```

In your case this would be changed to:

```
if (auth()->user()) {
     $file = Storage::disk('s3')->get($pathToFile);
     return response()->file($file);
} else {
    return 'Nope, sorry bro, access denied!';
}
```

**Note:** S3 driver supports multiple storage solutions: https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v1/docs/adapter/aws-s3-v2/